# CSS3 Border image strech

Tags: css

I'm trying to use the new CSS3 border-images I've created an image border to wrap around my content but I can't seem to stretch it all the way along my content it only sits in the corners.

```
border-style: solid;
border-width: 29px 27px;
-moz-border-image: url(http://i.imgur.com/oi4vSoL.png) 29 27 repeat;
-webkit-border-image: url(http://i.imgur.com/oi4vSoL.png) 29 27 repeat;
-o-border-image: url(http://i.imgur.com/oi4vSoL.png) 29 27 repeat;
border-image: url(http://i.imgur.com/oi4vSoL.png) 29 27 fill repeat;
border-image-outset: 17px;
```

I've created a fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/aLuzqtxg/

Comment: You can do this particular border without an image - with only borders and perhaps a little box-shadow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_border-image.asp
You should change 'repeat' to 'round' and make image slice/size and border-width smaller ex. 19 17

```css
border-style: solid;
border-width: 19px 17px;
-moz-border-image: url(http://i.imgur.com/oi4vSoL.png) 19 17 round;
-webkit-border-image: url(http://i.imgur.com/oi4vSoL.png) 19 17 round;
-o-border-image: url(http://i.imgur.com/oi4vSoL.png) 19 17 round;
border-image: url(http://i.imgur.com/oi4vSoL.png) 19 17 round;
border-image-outset: 17px;
```